# Error compiling with NASM in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: assembly, linker, visual-studio-2017, nasm, entry-point

I've downloaded and installed the VSNASM tool (located [here](https://github.com/ShiftMediaProject/VSNASM)), and everything works perfectly aside from the fact that when I compile, I get an error LNK1561, saying an entry point needs to be defined. I have no clue what to set the program's entry point as in the linker settings. Some help would be appreciated.

In case necessary, here's the code I'm attempting to run. It's a simple cat program:

```
section .data
    msg db "CAT test program. Press Esc to exit."
    msglen equ $-msg

section .bss
    char resb 1

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, msg
    mov edx, msglen
    int 80h

_loop:
    mov eax, 3
    mov ebx, 2
    mov ecx, char
    mov edx, 1
    int 80h

    mov [char], eax
    sub eax, 1Bh
    jz _end

    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, char
    mov edx, 1
    int 80h

    jmp _loop

_end
    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 0
    int 80h
```

Comment: I hope you aren't expecting this code to run as native Windows programs. `int 80h` is a Linux interrupt not supported in native Windows. This code won't even work if you created an exectuable program and ran it under Windows Subsystem for Linux since WSL doesn't support 32-bit executables.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I'll handle that before I compile.